# how to add a menu(navigation) in colorbox or fancybox

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, colorbox

i am trying to zoom a image like colorbox. I used colorbox [plugin](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example2/) of Jack Moore. I am trying to achieve anchor tag on the top of the image inspite of displaying the title. Here i showed the example of the anchor tag as item1, item2,...item5. If i selected an item the image must be changed.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are thumbnails acceptable? Fancybox 2 supports thumbnails... http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to replace the title, colorbox's title property takes HTML input so it could be anything you wanted it to be.  Example:

```
$('a.example').colorbox({title:"<p>Hello</p>"});
```